# Can I make a transaction using Etherjs without signer?

Tags: transactions, metamask, smart-contract-wallets, etherjs, ethsigner

Is it possible in EtherJS to execute a transaction/s without using signer ? Or If we could setup the signer one time and use that signer indefinitely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Through R&D, I found out that you cannot make transactions or call your smart contract for a transaction without a signer, So it is mandatory for you to use a signer. Also, The point of using a setting it up one time, Your using a front-end right. I'm using react and would enforce others to use it as well. Save the signer for the first time and every time you make a transaction check if the signer is already set in its useState, If it is null then connect with your meta-mask and save the signer in your use state and if you already have a signer then just make the transaction. If your making a full-stack app, then save the signer in the DB and just make a query to fetch it and use it.